# error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments / using a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Hi I get this error message when trying to compile this :

```
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> sptr(T* ptr)
{
 return std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr, &extension::IDeleteable::destroy);
}

costructorA(const Logger& _logger):logger(sptr(_logger.clone())) //here the error using sptr()
            {}
```

logger is type : `std::shared_ptr<Logger> logger;`

`class Logger` is :

```
    class GMRISK_FCUL_API Logger  : public IDeleteable{
    public:
        virtual ~Logger() {}
        virtual void destroy() const =0;
    };
```

`class IDeleateable`:

```
class IDeleteable
{
    public:
        virtual void destroy() const =0;

        template<typename T>
        static inline void destroy(T* value)
        {
            value->destroy();
        }
};
```

Here the complete error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(725): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(494) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::_Resetp<_Ux,_Dx>(_Ux *,_Dx)' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Ty=gmrisk::fcul::Logger,
          _Ux=gmrisk::fcul::Logger,
          _Dx=void (__thiscall extension::IDeleteable::* )(void) const
      ]
fcul_api.cpp(34) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::shared_ptr<T,void(__thiscall extension::IDeleteable::* )(void) const>(_Ux *,_Dx)' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Ty=gmrisk::fcul::Logger,
          T=gmrisk::fcul::Logger,
          _Ux=gmrisk::fcul::Logger,
          _Dx=void (__thiscall extension::IDeleteable::* )(void) const
      ]
```

Any idea which could produce this?

PD: the namespaces were not included here

Comment: You are missing a part of the error message, please copy the whole stuff.

Comment: -1 for "I get an error, here's the code, fix it"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To take a pointer to the static member function template, you need to explicitly instantiate it:

```
return std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr, &extension::IDeleteable::destroy<T>);
                                                               ^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ecatmur, I lost many hours trying to find the solution and modifying the implementation and the inheritances of the classes....